# WordPress RSS list add featured image link

Tags: wordpress, rss

I want wordpress post rss list featured image link

Ex:

```
<title>Test title</title>
<desc>Test desc</desc>
<image>imagelink</image>
```

I'm not using plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do. Add it to `functions.php` file:

```
// add the namespace to the RSS opening element

add_action( 'rss2_ns', 'custom_prefix_add_media_namespace' );

function custom_prefix_add_media_namespace() {
    echo "xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"n";
}

// add the requisite tag where a thumbnail exists
add_action( 'rss2_item', 'custom_prefix_add_media_thumbnail' );

function custom_prefix_add_media_thumbnail() {
    global $post;
    if( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) {
        $thumb_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
        $details = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_ID, 'thumbnail');
        if( is_array($details) ) {
            echo '<media:thumbnail url="' . $details[0] . '" width="' . $details[1] . '" height="' . $details[2] . '" />';
        }
    }
}
```

Also when you add this, be sure to reset the permalinks (flush them), by going to Settings > Permalinks, and either change permalinks to default, and back to your defined settings, or just re-saving.

After that, check your feed and the media should be there.